# How to order by column in nested level relationship in Laravel and get first order by?

Tags: laravel, nested, sql-order-by, one-to-many

I have two model.finance has many price.i want to get just one price (last  record according to time) for every finance.so used function and order by and first of each orderby.but this just works for first finance and the other i get null in the with relation.

```
public function prices()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Price::class, 'finance_id');
}

public function finances()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Finance::class, 'finance_id');
}
   $finances = Finance::with(['prices' => function ($query) {
        $query->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->first();
    }])->get();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create new relationship in your `Finance` model to get latest price:

```
public function latestPrice()
{
   return $this->hasOne(Price::class)->latest();
}
```

Change your query as below:

```
$finances = Finance::with('latestPrice')->get();
```

Comment: every finance must be have some prices dude.you change my problem to solve it :D.it is not one to one.it is one to many

Comment: Yes it is one to many, but you want only one record of price as per finance